# Matplotlib Legend Subtitles

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to have subtitles in my graph legend using matplotlib.
Is there any alternative to do this ?

Thx,

Best,

Comment: What do you mean with subtitle? Can you provide an example of something that looks like the result you want?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Do you want a text under the figure, a text inside the figure, a text for each object inside the graphics?

Comment: I plot 4 curves and I would like to have a titles for the two first curves and an other title for the two last.

Comment: I think if you include an image with a drawing of what you want, it would increase the probability of someone who knows how to do it come here and actually answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want legends for each line plotted, you can do this:

```
plt.plot(x, y1, label='Line One')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='Line Two')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Each `label` keyword argument provides the line's label, and the `legend()` command creates a box with legends inside. The optional `loc` argument (location) tries to prevent the legend box to be placed over the lines.

Comment: And what if you want to divide your legend in two parts with a main titles for each subparts and of course label for lines ..

Comment: I think you should create a custom legendbox then. Maybe there is some example in the Matplotlib Gallery, or maybe in the Matplotlib Cookbook, but if not you'll have to build one yourself, I think...